# LWJGL Texture doesn't work

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class GameManager {

    static int DEFAULT_DISPLAY_WIDTH = 855;
    static int DEFAULT_DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 485;

    public void startGame()
    {
        startGame("Unnamed Game");
    }

    public void startGame(String gameTitle)
    {

        new EventGameStart().run();

        try {
            Display.setTitle(gameTitle);
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(DEFAULT_DISPLAY_WIDTH,
                    DEFAULT_DISPLAY_HEIGHT));

            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        new GameLoader().load();
        Texture texture = null;
        try {
            texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("resources/ball.png"), true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            while (Keyboard.next()) {
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_F11
                        && Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
                    new EventFullscreen().run();
                }
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_F12
                        && Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
                    new EventScreenshot().run();
                }
            }


            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());

            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0 + 200, 0);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0 + 200, 0 + 200);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0 + 200);
            GL11.glEnd();

            Display.update();
        }

        new EventGameClose().run();
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

and the GameLoader():

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

/** Loads the game... */
public class GameLoader extends GameManager {
    /** Called by GameManager */
    public void load() {
        setUpOpenGL();
    }

    /** Loading the OpenGL Settings */
    private void setUpOpenGL()
    {
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), 0, Display.getHeight(), 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);    
    }
}
```

but if I start the script, i only see a black window :(.
I don't know what i should do.
The packages, I have included are the following:

```
-lwjgl.jar
-lwjgl_util.jar
-slick-util.jar
```

Any idea?
Thanks :D

Comment: Shame on you for calling it a "script" when it's actually a program!

Comment: Where is the different? Is there a definiton when a script is a program?

Comment: Basically programs are executed as a standalone program. Where script are interpreted within/through another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're missing the `glTexCoord`'s.

You need to add `glTexCoord`'s before all `glVertex` calls, the `glTexCoord` takes two parameters the `U` & `V` location on the texture.

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0 + 200, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0 + 200, 0 + 200);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0 + 200);
GL11.glEnd();
```

#### Edit - Comment Request

You need to specify the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` & `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`.

If you want to keep the pixel look to the texture, you would do the following.

```
texture.bind(); // First you bind your texture
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
```

and if you want them back to being "blury", you would do the following.

```
texture.bind(); // First you bind your texture
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
```

Remember that for multiple textures you need to call them individually, like this.

```
texture1.bind();
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);

texture2.bind();
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! :D What can I do for you?

Comment: You're welcome! :) Well you could click the "accept" button to accept my question if it works! :)

Comment: If I want, that the texure is resized like in minecraft, that the pixel repeats and its every time sharp, what i have to do?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Do you mean how you remove the "blury" effect and only use the pixelated version of the texture.

Comment: I have a big image (1024 x 1024 px) with a lot of icons. For the texture on the quad I want to get the part of the image between x 128 y 64 and x 256 y 192. How can I do this?

Comment: You do know that you are surpose to ask a new question right? and not just extending the question :)

Comment: New Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300816/getting-a-part-of-a-texture-lwjgl

Comment: Yea I actually do! :)

Comment: Then PLEASE replay to the new question ;)

Comment: @ThomasFlynn why did you remove the question?